# Add images in jar dynamically

Tags: java, image, swing, jfilechooser

How to add images in jar dynamically? Is it even possible?

In my swing project I let the user select his `user_image` using `JFileChooser`. Now I'm not able to use database. So I think if I can add the uploaded image in jar and then fetch it. Should it be a valid way? Or any other idea to do this? How can I efficiently save images so that my swing app can access it. The number of images is not fixed cause images will be uploaded by multiple user on the same machine using same jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have an *app directory from which your app is reading images* and make this dir configurable using [Preference-API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html)

Comment: @Jigar: Its not perfect solution as I can see: if user deletes the directory.What then???

Comment: then your app should create a new dir with same name, and you will loose those images. user can delete images from anywhere, unless its your server

Comment: @Jigar: its not an internet app that uses a server to get data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure store dynamic data in jar is good idea. If you create dynamic local application you can use some **working directory**. Or you can use http connection to work with **remote images storage**. Or you can use a **DB**.

Or you develop something like flexible interface such as:

```
public interface ImageProvider {
  public void storeImage(MyImageClass image, String imageLable);
  public MyImageClass getImage(String imageLable);
}
```

.

And implement it by classes as long as your application is being developed:

```
public class ImageJarProvider implements ImageProvider { // jar solution
  private File jar = null;
  public ImageJarProvider(File jar) {
    this.jar = jar;
  }
  public void storeImage(MyImageClass image, String imageLable) {
     // implement jar repack:
     // use classes JarFile, ZipEntry and ZipOutputStream.
     // unpack file
     JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(jar);
     ZipEntry inputEntry = jarFile.getEntry("path/you/need/to/file");
     File outFile = new File("temp.jar");
     FileOutputStream zipFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
     ZipOutputStream zipOutStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(zipFileStream));
     ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("filename you pack");
     zipOutStream.putNextEntry(entry);
     //pack all your files and pack new image.
     //this code just shows how to unpack and pack zip(jar)-archives.
     BufferedInputStream origin = new BufferedInputStream(new jarFile.getInputStream(inputEntry));
     byte data[] = new byte[2048];
     int count = 0;
     while((count = origin.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
       zipOutStream.write(data, 0, count);
     }
     zipOutStream.close();
     origin.close();
  }

  public MyImageClass getImage(String imageLable) {
     // implement unpack of image
     ...
  }
}

public class ImageHttpProvider implements ImageProvider { // http solution
  public ImageHttpProvider(String host, int port) {
     ...
  }

  public void storeImage(MyImageClass image, String imageLable) {
     // implement image upload
     ...
  }

  public MyImageClass getImage(String imageLable) {
     // implement HTTP image download
     ...
  }
}

public class ImageDirProvider implements ImageProvider { // working directory solution
  public ImageDirProvider(File dir) {
     ...
  }

  public void storeImage(MyImageClass image, String imageLable) {
     // implement file work
     ...
  }

  public MyImageClass getImage(String imageLable) {
     // implement file work
     ...
  }
}

public class ImageDBProvider implements ImageProvider { // DB solution
  public ImageDBProvider(String jdbcURL, Properties jdbcProperties) {
     ...
  }

  public void storeImage(MyImageClass image, String imageLable) {
     // implement jdbc clob
     ...
  }

  public MyImageClass getImage(String imageLable) {
     // implement jdbc clob
     ...
  }
}
```

.

You can organize storing and reading of images as you want without changes in engine of your application.